# Header search paths in Xcode 11.x?

Tags: xcode, header-files

I'm trying to build a flex/bison/c app using Xcode's command-line-tool settings. There are a total of five files, including two headers.

The code uses glib, which is `brew install...`ed, all the files are there in the Cellar and /usr/local/include/glib-2.0/, but Xcode can't find any of it, so when it gets to the .y file, which `#include <glib.h>`, it `file not found`s.

I see that the canonical solution is to include `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` and `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0` in the build settings to properly expand the paths. The typical suggestion is to place it in Build Settings / Other Linker Flags.

However, none of the suggested settings exist in my project or target. They don't seem to be included in Xcode 11 (and 10 too, I think).

Does anyone know the proper incantations in 11?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, this is just some Xcode dumbness. By default, Xcode now hides unchanged settings, so all the settings you need are simply off the screen. So...

1. In your target, click Build Settings and then make sure the All button is clicked on the next line
2. Use the search bar for "other linker" and add the paths to your library, in this case `/usr/local/opt/glib/lib/libglib-2.0.dylib`
3. Use search again for "header search" and add the paths, in my case `/usr/local/include/glib-2.0` and make it recursive, and `/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.62.3/lib/glib-2.0/include`, which was needed because the config file is in the later

Build went fine then... freakishly fast too, which is nice.